# Recursion vs Callback function in chrome bookmarks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, recursion, google-chrome-extension, callback

I'm trying to write a function using the chrome bookmarks api to create a hierarchical set of bookmarks. I can traverse the tree fine with a recursive function.

But when creating the bookmarks, that won't work because of the asynchronous nature of the API. `chrome.bookmarks.create(object bookmark, function callback())` takes the bookmark node data as the first parameter, and a callback function as the second parameter; that callback is where you'd get the id of the new node ([api reference](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks#method-create)).

I have this data structure for my hierarchy:

```
var newbookmarks = [
    { title: 'bookmark1',
      url: 'foo.com'
      submenu: []
    },
    { title: 'Submenu1',
      submenu: [
        { title: 'bookmark1.1',
          url: 'bar.org',
          submenu: []
        },
        { title: 'bookmark1.2',
          url: 'baz.com',
          submenu: []
        }
      ]
    },
    { title: 'bookmark2',
      url: 'bletch.edu',
      submenu: []
    }
];
```

It's an array of node objects, each of which has a submenu element that itself can be an array of node objects.

My first thought to create the hierarchy recursively just like the traverse function:

```
createBookmarkNodes(parentid, bookmarks) {
  var i,newnode;
  for (i=0; i<bookmarks.length; i++) {
    newnode = chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId: parentid, title: bookmarks[i].title, url: bookmarks[i].url});
    if (bookmarks[i].submenu.length > 0) {
      createBookmarkNodes(newnode.id, bookmarks[i].submenu);
    }
  }
}
```

This won't work, because create doesn't return the node I need for the parent id of sub-menus, you can't find it until you get to the callback. But once inside the callback, I don't know where I am in the newbookmarks data structure.

```
function installBookmarkNodes(parentid, bookmarks) {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<bookmarks.length, i++) {
        chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId: parentid, title: bookmarks[i].title, url: bookmarks[i].url}, create_callback);
    }
}
function create_callback(bookmarkobj) {
    var child-nodes-of-this-bookmark = ???;
    for (child-nodes-of-this-bookmark) {
        chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId: bookmarkobj.parentId, title: ???, url: ???}, create_callback);
    }
}
```

How do I keep my place in the new bookmarks data structure within the callback paradigm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the recursive call into the callback:

```js
createBookmarkNodes(parentid, bookmarks) {
    bookmarks.forEach(function(bm) {
        chrome.bookmarks.create({
            parentId: parentid,
            title: bm.title,
            url: bm.url
        }, function(result) {
            if (bm.submenu && bm.submenu.length > 0) {
                createBookmarkNodes(result.id, bm.submenu);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Duh, thanks. I was actually headed that direction, but it didn't work with the array index notation I was using; the scope of the index didn't make it to the callback. Using 'forEach' did the trick, though.

Comment: Yup, because `bookmarks` wasn't in the function local scope.